# Using Java code how to trigger my Lambda Function when a new file is uploaded to s3 bucket

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am a new baby to AWS world. I have one requirement please help me to get my query.
I wrote one lambda function to read file content from s3 bucket and it stores the details inside my PostgreSQL RDS instance in AWS. Fortunately it works fine!!!!
My lambda function name is 'MyFunction'. Now I want to do the following. If a new file fall on my s3 bucket 's3-testing' automatically lambda function 'MyFunction' should work.

Is there any way to do this.I am using eclipse to create my lambda function.

Please help me to get this.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common requirement: Invoke a Lambda function for new files in an S3 bucket.

Amazon S3 supports events. When a new object (other actions are also supported) arrives in S3, and event is created. This event can be sent to an SNS Topic, SQS Queue or a Lambda function.

Your Lambda function will receive an event data structure. This structure details information about the S3 event.

This tutorial will walk you thru setting up S3 to invoke your Lambda function.

[Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. ne more question I have my s3 bucket 'testing'.  Inside my bucket i have one folder called 'SampleData'. Inside that folder i uploaded 2 files csv1 and csv2. I wrote a code to read file from bucket , I mentioned bucket name and key name. What is actually key? if i want to read csv1 my key is SampleData\csv1?

Comment: In some case i need to read data from csv1 and other case I need data from csv2. In my current program i just added 2 lines of code to get the bucket name and key. I am hard-coded the names.In key value i need to get latest file uploaded inside s3. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: The key name is SampleData/csv1 and SampleData/csv2. S3 does not have folders so the key name is always the full path name.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. :-)